# gruntjs 0.4 registerHelper deprecated, syntax fix?

Tags: node.js, build, module, task, gruntjs

I've been running the following task for grunt 0.3 and moved to 0.4 and registerHelper has been deprecated.  What is the correct method of implementing this with the new API.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var crypto = require('crypto');

grunt.registerTask('wpversion', 'Set the versions in scripts.php for CSS/JS', function() {
  var scriptsPhp = 'src/lib/include_functions/scripts.php';

  // Hash the CSS
  var hashCss = grunt.helper('md5', 'dist/assets/css/main.min.css');

  // Hash the JS
  var hashJs = grunt.helper('md5', 'dist/assets/scripts/scripts.min.js');

  // Update scripts.php to reference the new versions
  var regexCss = /(wp_enqueue_style\('main_css',(\s*[^,]+,){2})\s*[^\)]+\);/;
  var regexJs = /(wp_register_script\('main_js',(\s*[^,]+,){2})\s*[^,]+,\s*([^\)]+)\);/;

  var content = grunt.file.read(scriptsPhp);
  content = content.replace(regexCss, "\$1 '" + hashCss + "');");
  content = content.replace(regexJs, "\$1 '" + hashJs + "', " + "\$3);");
  grunt.file.write(scriptsPhp, content);
  grunt.log.writeln('"' + scriptsPhp + '" updated with new CSS/JS versions.');
});

/**
* The 'md5' helper is a basic wrapper around crypto.createHash
*/
grunt.registerHelper('md5', function(filepath) {
  var hash = crypto.createHash('md5');
  hash.update(fs.readFileSync(filepath));
  grunt.log.write('Versioning ' + filepath + '...').ok();
  return hash.digest('hex');
});
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make it a normal function. If it's large put it in an separate file and require it. If it's reusable for other tasks, publish it as a node module so that other tasks can make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

The grunt-helpers are deprecated in favor of node's `require`. 
There is a project to help use the legacy helpers:

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-lib-legacyhelpers